# CSS3 Curved backgrounds css or background image for non responsive website?

Tags: css

I have been asked to create a page with css / html from a design.

The main background is curved and has 2 colors.

I don't know what the best / fastest way to go around this design is...background image or curved the image with css3.

Here is the design bg image ... what's the best way to go around this design?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple pure CSS rounded background with content in a container demo:

http://codepen.io/serkai/pen/JdaYjX

Example compiled CSS here:

```
.bg-border-radius {
  margin: -400px auto 0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0 0 70% 70%;
  background-color: #0080C1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a solid color. I would just define that area as a div and use background border-radius pure css.

*ie*

```
.strangeblueelement { 
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 25px; // toggle til you get your effect
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
}
```

another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u5U57/146/).

*Take a look at this article -- you could go as far making a nice little circle just using css.*

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Comment: Yes, use CSS here.  Saves http requests and is easier to maintain.

Comment: Exactly also well supported at this point.

Comment: May i suggest using border-radius: ...% instead of px: http://jsfiddle.net/u5U57/175/